# Google maps code not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps and I'm trying to create a polygon on the map but for some reason google just gives me the map with no polygon

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var infoWindow;
  var sandCoodrs;

function initialize() {


  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26, 28);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  var sandtonCoords = [];
```

//For some reason after this point firebug doesn't step into the code and sandtonCoords remains null and hence no polygon

```
  jQuery.get('http://localhost/magnetic/Main.txt', function(data) 
    {
        var StringData = data;
        StringData.trim();
        var MainArray = data.split(",");
        var length = MainArray.length;
        for(k=0;k<length;k++)
        {
            var StringCoords = MainArray[k];
            var LatLongArray = StringCoords.split(" ");
            var Lat = parseFloat(LatLongArray[0]);
            Lat.trim();
            var Long = parseFloat(LatLongArray[1]);
            Long.trim();
            sandtonCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Long));
        }
    });

andton = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: sandtonCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  sandton.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(sandton, 'click', showArrays);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}`
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the map and what is the content of Main.txt?

Answer (score 0):

LatLongArray is an array of strings. Latitude and longitude are numeric values and the type conversion is not automatic. Therefore:

```
var Lat = parseFloat(LatLongArray[0]);
var Long = parseFloat(LatLongArray[1]);
```

by the way, make sure that your pairs in Main.txt are [lat lon] and not [lon lat].

Comment: The content of the textfile : -25.949094 28.0123866,-25.949094 28.0123866, etc. Also when I use firebug in mozilla everything seems to be fine, think the error might come in is when the sandtonCoords var is filled in the jQuery function it is then destroyed. Afterwards when I am referring back to sandtonCoords its null and hence no polygon. Thank for the reply

Comment: So your polygon is in South Africa? Did you try using parseFloat() as I suggested?

Comment: Yip polygon is for a south african area called Sandton and yes I did use the parseFloat. The sandtonCoords its created in the jQuery.get('http://localhost/magnetic/Main.txt', function(data) function but when I try reference the sandtonCoords again when making the polygon firebug says sandtonCoords is null

Comment: Is var sandtonCoords = []; truly global or is it defined inside a function? Might need to see the rest of your code.

Comment: ReferenceError: sandtonCoords is not defined the error from firebug

Comment: var sandtonCoords = [] is not global. it is defined inside function initialize() and thus local to that function. Move the declaration outside the function, together with var map; var infoWindow; var sandtonCoords = [] ;

Comment: Okay, fixed that problem. There is something wrong in the jQuery function as firebug steps right over it and ignores it. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Then feel free to accept the answer. Glad I was able to help. :)